# How can I plot a 1-D plot in R?

Tags: r, plot

I have a vector of integers, e.g.: `2,8,11,19`.

I would like to plot a line of length e.g. 20 then plot a dot for each value that exist in the list (at some constant height), so I get something like this:

`-+-----+--+-------+-`

Comment: Alternative: `hist(x)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Brandon Bertelsen is really close...

```
x <- c(2,8,11,19)
x <- data.frame(x,1) ## 1 is your "height"
plot(x, type = 'o', pch = '|', ylab = '')
```

But I wrote this mostly to mention that you might also in base graphics look at stripchart() and rug() for ways to look at 1-d data.

Answer (score 8):

```
library(lattice)


x <- c(2, 8, 11, 19)
stripplot(x)
```

you can adjust the scales to your liking. see `?stripplot`

Answer (score 6):

This can be done using `ggplot2` by removing all the axis and plotting on a constant y value. You can then use the usual `ggplot2` functions to change the colours of the dots, and annotate with text, more lines etc.

[image]

```
library(ggplot2)

x=c(2,8,11,19)

ggplot(data.frame(x), aes(x=x, y=0)) +
  geom_point(size = 10)  +
  annotate("segment",x=1,xend=20, y=0, yend=0, size=2) +
  annotate("segment",x=1,xend=1, y=-0.1,yend=0.1, size=2) +
  annotate("segment",x=20,xend=20, y=-0.1,yend=0.1, size=2) +
  geom_text(aes(label = x), col="white") +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(1,20)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-1,1)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = unname(colours)) + 
  theme(panel.background = element_blank(),
        axis.text = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        axis.title = element_blank())
```

This plot is essentially a straight line centered around 0 with two more line segments added at the ends as stoppers. `annotate("segment",...)` is preferential to a reference line as you can control how long the line is drawn.

Answer (score 4):

With the base graphics:

```
x <- c(2,8,11,19)
x <- data.frame(x,1) ## 1 is your "height"
plot(x, type="b")
```

Answer (score 4):

This may be helpful for those plotting one-dimensional ordinal data.

```
x<-c(-1.5,2,2.5,-2,.05)
## Make y-value=0
x<-cbind(x,0)
## Plotting without box or axis with dot, representing data points                  
plot(x,bty='n',xaxt='n',yaxt='n',ylab='',xlab='',pch=21,cex=2)

## Placing axis at y-value in order to pass through points with sequence wider than range
axis(side=1,seq(-4,4,1),pos=0)  ## Using y-value as position 

## Placing x-values & x-axis label onto plot
text(x,labels=x[,1],pos=3,offset=1,font=2)
text(y=0,x=0,labels='One-Dimensional Plot',pos=1,offset=3,font=2)
```

Comment: Finally an answer where the box/axix is not shown. Thanks!

Comment: Very Nice, Old Chap. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Interestingly, nobody has mentioned `stripchart`

```
stripchart(x, pch = "+")
```

You can use `add = TRUE` to add the stripchart to an existing plot, and the `at` parameter to define the y value at which to plot your data.