# R: 1 Dimensional "scatterplot"

Tags: r, plotly, data-visualization, scatter-plot, data-manipulation

I am using the R programing language. Recently, I came across this previous stackoverflow post where it describes how to make a 1 dimensional scatter plot in R: [How can I plot a 1-D plot in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3798676/how-can-i-plot-a-1-d-plot-in-r):

```
x <- rnorm(100,10,10)
x <- data.frame(x,1) ## 1 is your "height"
plot(x, type = 'o', pch = '|', ylab = '')
```

My question: is it possible to transform the above plot into a "plotly" plot?

Suppose I have the following data:

```
library(plotly)
x <- rnorm(100,10,10)
color <- rnorm(100, 2,1)
frame = data.frame(x,color)
```

Would it be possible to do something like this?

```
fig <- plot_ly(data = frame, x = ~frame$x, color ~ frame$color )

fig
```

I get the following error when running this code:

```
No trace type specified:
  Based on info supplied, a 'histogram' trace seems appropriate.
```

Can someone please show me how to do this?
Thanks

Source: https://plotly.com/r/line-and-scatter/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `plotly` language, a *trace* is the type of visualization that you would like to use to display your data. So the error basically lets you know that you have not specified any trace and that the program is picking one for you: "a histogram". For scatterplots, you need `type = "scatter"` and `mode = "markers'`.

Also, inside the `plot_ly()` function, once you specify the `data` argument, you can simply access the columns with the column name preceded by a tilde `~`.

Finally, since you want a one dimensional scatterplot along the x-axis, you need to add `y = " "` to the `plot_ly()` function.

This is how you can achieve your desired result:

```
library(plotly)

x <- rnorm(100,10,10)
color <- rnorm(100, 2,1)
frame = data.frame(x,color)

plot_ly(type = "scatter", mode = "markers", data = frame, x = ~x, y = " ", color = ~color )
```

Note that `plotly` is a very rich framework and you can read the appropriate documentation to learn how to customize your plot to your liking.

Comment: thank you for your answer! this is perfect, I can not thank you enough for your answer! I recently learned you can also use the "size" option in plotly

Comment: this also works! plot_ly(type = "scatter", mode = "markers", data = frame, x = ~x, y = " ", color = ~color, size = x )