# Create one-dimensional plot in R with text labels

Tags: r

I want to create a simple one-dimensional plot in R ranging from 0 to ten, with a scale (small lines for integer values 1,2, etc.), a slightly higher line for 5 (the median) and slightly higher than all of the other for 0 and 10. Then I want to fill this plot with a few points representing values like 2, 4, 5, 6, 8, and a text above each one of them with corresponding labels (like "party voted", "closest party", "individual 1", "expert", "individual 2"). It can be smaller labels, like "PV", "CP", etc.

I would like to have control over shape and color (say in data-points 4 and 6 I have a circle filled in black but in position 2 I have a not filled square, in position 5 I have a green circle filled-in, and in position 8 I have a black triangle, also filled).  I would like to have 0, 10 and 5 marked in the labels as well.

A very rough representation of what I am trying to draw is in the image below (it has all the elements I want, at least).

In this [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3798676/how-can-i-plot-a-1-d-plot-in-r) there is some code on one-dimension plot, I have tried to adapt it to what I need but didn't get to it

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've assumed from the link in the question that you are looking for a base R solution.

There may be more efficient solutions but this seems to get you where you want.

I've avoided the need for arrows by forcing the labels to run over two lines and reducing the text size on the plot so they do not overlap.

You could manage this with arrows if need be, but this seems it will need a lot of extra code.

```r
# data

df <- data.frame(desc = c("Party voted", "Closest party", "Individual 1", "Expert", "Individual 2"),
                 score = c(2, 4, 5, 6, 8),
                 y = 1)

# add line break to labels
df$desc <- gsub("\\s", "\n", df$desc)


plot(df$score,
     df$y,
     # type = "o",
     xlim = c(0, 10),
     pch = c(1, 21,21,21, 24),
     col = c("black", "black", "green", "black", "black"),
     bg = c("black", "black", "green", "black", "black"),
     cex = 1.5,
     xaxt = "n", #remove tick marks
     yaxt = "n",
     ylab = '', # remove axis labels
     xlab = '',
     bty = "n") # remove bounding box
axis(side = 1,
     0:10,
     pos = df$y,
     labels = FALSE,
     tck = 0.02)
axis(side = 1,
     0:10,
     pos = df$y,
     labels = c(0, rep("", 4), 5, rep("", 4), 10),
     tck = -0.02)
axis(side = 1,
     c(0, 5, 10),
     pos = df$y,
     labels = FALSE,
     tck = 0.05)
axis(side = 1,
     c(0, 5, 10),
     pos = df$y,
     labels = FALSE,
     tck = -0.05)
text(x = df$score,
     y = df$y,
     labels = df$desc,
     pos = 3,
     offset = 1,
     cex = 0.75)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-04-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you. 

It doesn't have to be base R, but it's a good option. 

I don't need arrows , it's just that sometimes in plots like this it gets hard to see which label belongs to each data point. May I ask what part of the code assigns shapes and filled/ not filled , in case I want to adapt for similar images?

Comment: Oh, is there any way of reducing size of labels (which is a column here, right?)

Comment: In the call to `text(...)` reduce the value of the `cex` argument, for example try `cex = 0.5`. You'll have to experiment with various values to get one you are happy with.

Comment: Shapes are defined by the `pch` (plot character) argument; your best bet is to search on line. A randomly selected search I just did produced this link: https://r-lang.com/pch-in-r/ which seems a good start.